# What is the correct way to make the (non-numbered) titles of a numbered progressive list?

Tags: html

What is the correct way to make the (non-numbered) titles of a numbered progressive list?

The following code is simple (it allows me to have a progressive list whose numbers automatically update when new items are inserted, but if I had a numbered sub-list I would have to change the starting numbers each time I add an item to the previous sub-list) but I'm afraid it's not correct, I get the error:

> the 'strong' tag may not be a direct child of the 'ol' tag

```html
<ol>
   <strong>A</strong>
   <li>A1</li>
   <li>A2</li>
   <li>A3</li>
   <strong>B</strong>
   <li>B1</li>
   <li>B2</li>
   <li>B3</li>
</ol>
```

In other words, if I add an item to the sub-list "A", the numbering of the subsequent lists must be updated accordingly (A-1234 ... B-567).

**EDIT:**
"*Melius re perpensa*" (thinking better), the best solution for the purpose of my question is ... to change the question.
Instead of a list, better a table, with automatic row numbering (excluding the headings), as shown in the following code.

```css
table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr:not(.header) {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr:not(.header) td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
}
```

```html
<table>
     <tr class="header">
        <th>A</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> A2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
        <th> B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> B1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> B2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> B3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: nest your lists. You have an list of big letter titles, and inside each one you have a numbered list of subtitles.

Comment: Yes, <strong> as a child of <ol> is an error, and it may lead to differences in display between browsers. There have been browsers in the past that put the text "**B**" on the same line as the "A3", for instance. So don't do that.

Comment: It helps that the [OP has clarified since my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49939172/revisions) @MrLister

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this; dispense with the `<strong>`s and create pseudo numbering of your own.

```css
ol li[class] {
  margin-top: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
}

ol li[class]::before {
  content: attr(class);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 700;
  top: -1.2em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="A">A1</li>
  <li>A2</li>
  <li>A3</li>
  <li class="B">B1</li>
  <li>B2</li>
  <li>B3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: The end result is what I wanted, thank you. The tool is really much longer (20 lines of css code) than the violation of html nesting rules... I adapt to these, thanks again

Comment: OK. I shortened the CSS a bit; how's this? This one also has the advantage of not needing additional CSS if you want to include more sides.

Answer (score -1):

Use nested lists, ul and or ol. You can hide the dot with css:

```css
ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><strong>A</strong>
    <ol>
      <li>A1</li>
      <li>A2</li>
      <li>A3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <strong>B</strong>
    <ol>
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>B2</li>
      <li>B3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I thin the OP wants `123...456` not `123...123`

Comment: @Liam no? Hes header is A and B and items A1, A2.. B1, B2. I thought this is what he wants

Comment: @Liam Well, we tried, hopefully he edits the question to be more clear :)